# How to use result receiver in a static way

Tags: android, callback, intentservice

I think [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services) is good description given on how to use the service and getting the callback. So I was following the result receiver and using intent service. In my app I have some goals And I am able to receive those goals partially somehow. My goals of app is as under

1. When I start the intent service with my activity I would like to get the download status from the result receiver (As I am performing some downloading stuff in the service.)
2. I started to get the call back and gets my view updated. (I have a text view which gets updated from callback.)

**Problem**

3. This is the last point where I see the problem. When I press back and come back to my activity , I can not see my text view getting updated any more , where as I can see that I am getting the call back from the service.

I know my Text view getting initialized again, but the other way that when Ever I come back in that activity , I can get my text view updating along with the call back.

Please help me , as I am 90 percent near to my app goal . Only one thing is making delay . please help.

Comment: what do you mean by static way

Comment: I mean I can get updates until and unless my service in background.

Comment: I have post the link , I am following the same way

Comment: and this is why you should use a `"local bound service"` pattern, google for `bound services`

Comment: I have  read this , But I think you have not got my point. Local bound service no doubt can interact with each other , but I want updates sending from service to acitivity.

Comment: `"but I want updates sending from service to acitivity."` so as i said: use local bound service

Comment: if I go back or finished the activity at all , but the service is working (As designed), and coming back to activity again, will it show the stats from the point service is approached

Comment: `will it show the stats from the point service is approached` i have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I mean I have Intent service downloading images let say there are fifty images , and each image is getting download one by one ,, and in notification area I am showing notification with the progress which telling the user how much images are remaining. I want to show that progress also in textview of the activity

Comment: Right now it is working with my technique , but When I go back and destroy activity and comes again in the activity , the textview never gets updated

Comment: see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) and skip to ~25 min or watch the whole video